# nested ifelse statement - multiple values for 1 output

Tags: r, if-statement, nested

I have a dataset with a variable with values from 1 to 5.
I want to create a new column where values 1 and 3 become A, 2 and 4  become B and 5 becomes C

```
data$new <- ifelse(data$value == c("1", "3"), "A",  
                                 ifelse(data$value == c("2", "4"), "B", "C"))
```

This works for 1, 2 and 5. But for some reason it doesn't accept me putting multiple numbers for A and B. How can I tell R to create A if it is 1 or 3?

Answer (score 2):

I think here you should use operator `%in%`.
It works like this:

```
> '5' %in% c('1', '3', '5')
[1] TRUE
> '2' %in% c('1', '3', '5')
[1] FALSE
```

On contrary, the equality `==` works like this:

```
> '2' == c('2', '4')
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

-- it actually outputs array of two booleans. And probably `ifelse` takes the first one of the array as the result of the test.

So, in your example it is used as `data$value %in% c("1", "3")` -- each value of the `data$value` array is tested to be in the given array.

PS

Also notice -- in your example you use strings `'1'`, `'2'` etc -- check if you really want strings there, and not `numeric`s.